# Using jQuery how do you prompt a message with a select menu option?

Tags: jquery, webforms

I need to prompt an alert message when a user selects a particular option in a select menu.  Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your select has an ID of myselect, and the value you want to check is "myval"

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "myval")
    {
       alert('message');
    }
});
```

I havent tested this but the concept should be sound

Answer (score 0):

I recently bumped into the [jQuery Confirm Plugin](http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin). It may or may be what you are looking for.